# How do I remove specific parameters from URL in splunk?

Tags: splunk, splunk-query

/app/account-headless#state=FD=reqdoc&PN=952949&accessMode=Internet&accessType=MOBILE

In splunk, I would like to group by the URLs by filtering/removing the parameter based on parameter name, for example remove PN=952949 or accessType=MOBILE

Answer (score 0):

Try using `sed` to remove the undesired parameters.  You'll need one `sed` command for each parameter.

```
| rex mode=sed field=URL "s/[?&]PN=[^&$]+//"
| rex mode=sed field=URL "s/[?&]accessType=[^&$]+//"
```

Answer (score 0):

@RichG [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73649017/4418) [`rex`](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/SearchReference/rex) in `sed` mode

You can also use a pair of [`eval`](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/SearchReference/eval) [`replace`](http://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/SearchReference/TextFunctions#replace.28X.2CY.2CZ.29) calls:

```
| eval URL=replace(URL,"\&PN=[^\&]+","")
| eval URL=replace(URL,"\&accessType=[^\&]+","")
```